# returning query in oracle function

Tags: oracle, function, return-value

i am new to oracle database. Trying to make a simple function but it is returning complete select query  which is in single quotes. I do not know why. kindly help. and yes! it in the end of function compiling also says "hint: nm parameter never used" I am confused.

```html
-- function to return a single letter grade

create or replace function update_grade(nm number) return varchar2
as
grd varchar2(3);
begin
grd := 'select gradeid from grade where nm between marks_s and markks_e';
return grd;
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not executing any query. You are just assigning the query string to the returned result variable. 
I've not tried to compile it, but something like this:

```
    create or replace function update_grade(nm number) return varchar2
    as
    grd varchar2(3);
    begin
    SELECT gradeid  INTO grd from grade where nm between marks_s and markks_e;
    return grd;
    end;
```

You might consider adding handling for the case when no data is found:

```
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        grd:= NULL;
```

Comment: thankyou much. I guess the issue was that i was using trying to equalize select statement with  declared variable(grd)